# Nginx is redirecting 1 subdomain on another subdomain issue?

Tags: linux, nginx, centos7

I had configured the subdomain `forums.subdomain.net`

It was working fine I added 1 redirect and removed that redirect after that it is now always redirect to another subdomain.

```
server {
    listen       80 ;

    server_name  forums.domain.net www.forums.domain.net;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /var/www/foldername.com/html_backup;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }        

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

`https://forums.onesoftwares.net/wp/wp-admin/` trying to access this path.

subdomain name is filesvr.subdomain.net main domain is https://onesoftwares.net

Note: No redirect code is added in the config file.

Comment: Browser cache? Try resetting the browser's cache.

Comment: tried multiple times, try to open in different browsers, and also in incognito.

Comment: Maybe you’ve failed to restart Nginx. Check the error logs.

Comment: I restart Nginx on every change in the config file.

Comment: Please show the _complete_ `server` block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had updated the server block code. Complete config file code.

Comment: There is no redirect there. Check your web application.

Comment: @MichaelHampton when you hit `http://forums.onesoftwares.net/` it will redirect to `https://forums.onesoftwares.net/login` and it display some other subdomain login page.

Comment: That redirect comes from your PHP code. We cannot help you with PHP here.